# Ajax Response cant able to print all

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is My ajax I have 20 response But i cant able to print all value in my html.

**`My Ajax`**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   dataType: 'text',
   data: {date: id,customerId:customerId},
   success: function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        $('.loading-mask').hide();
        var count = Object.keys(obj.item).length;
        if(count){
            $.each(obj.item, function(index,item) {   
                $("#calender_details h1").html(item.name);
                $("#calender_details .qty").html('Quantity : '+item.quantity); 
                $('[name="subscription_img"]').attr("src", item.image);
                $('[name="subscription_img"]').attr("alt", item.name);
                $('[name="url"]').attr("href", item.url);
                $('[name="url"]').attr("title", item.name);
                $("#calender_no_details").hide();
                $('#calender_details').show();
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#calender_details').hide();
            $("#calender_no_details").show();
            $("#calender_no_details h1").html("No Data...");
        }
   }
 });
```

**`My Html`**

```
<!-- With Details Html -->
    <div id="calender_details">
        <a href="" name="url" title="">
            <img src="" alt="" name="subscription_img">
        </a>
        <h1></h1>
        <span></span>
        <p class="qty"></p>
    </div>
    <!-- With Details Html -->

    <!-- Without Details Html -->
    <div id="calender_no_details">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Without Details Html -->
```

How to print all value what is the mistake i made here?

How to fix this ?

My Axaj response count is 20 but i can't able to print all 20

it will show last response value only

Comment: It seems that you have to create all divs 20 time dynamically through the code itself. currently in single div you are pasting response, that is the problem. If you use `append()` instead of `html()` also, i don't think a proper out-put you will get

Comment: Can you show what you want the resulting HTML to look like for a few items (not all 20)?

Comment: {  
   "item":[  
      0{  
         "id":"1",
         "cuid":"1",
         "product_sku":"1",
         "pid":"1",
         "name":"1",
         "image":"1",
         "amount":"1",
         
      }
      1{  
         "id":"2",
         "cuid":"2",
         "product_sku":"2",
         "pid":"2",
         "name":"2",
         "image":"2",
         "amount":"2",
         
      }

}

Comment: For some reason i dont want append